# Datatables with Rails cycle is not highlighting every other row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, datatables

I have a Rails 4 application with working datatables in a view. I'm calling a `%td` to cycle through every other row. I tried appending the cycle class to `%tr`instead of `%td`, but that doesn't do any highlighting at all, for some strange reason.

There really isn't a specific pattern in the table as to which items are even or which are odd. Could go 7 rows without any highlighting and then 4 rows in a row with highlighting. Any suggestions, or ideas why this is happening?

My View:

```
%table.table.tickets-table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Tickets
  %tbody
    - @support_queue.tickets.each do |ticket|
      %tr
        %td{:class => cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}
          = render ticket.ticket_condition if ticket.ticket_condition
          = ticket.id
          \-
          \#{link_to ticket.name, [@support_queue, ticket]}
```

In my CSS, I have the following:

```
.list_line_even {
    background: #ccc;
}

.list_line_odd {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Looks like it's picking up correctly in the web browser as well as far as even-odd cycle for each tr with CSS. (tried posting an image, not enough rep :()

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

are you using bootstrap if so try adding the class `table-striped` to your `table`?

for example

```
%table.table.tickets-table.table-striped
```

if that doesn't work what does your dataTable js look like?

adding this option could help

```
sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
```

Comment: But it did not answer the question. I have this problem and now there is still no solution because you accepted this answer.